# Defining and adding values to arrays inside an array in VBA Excel

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an "input array" (wich listcount is not fixed). I need to create a new array for each item inside that "input array", and add each item as the first item of its own array.

I can't define the array of arrays' size, because the amount of sub-arrays is not fixed.

How should it be defined?

Comment: What???????????

Comment: Welcome to S.O! Have you tried anything? If so, please, provide the code, take a look to the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `Redim` (that was too short, so [I'll also suggest reading this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3064/arrays/16562/dynamic-arrays-array-resizing-and-dynamic-handling)).

Comment: You might envisage to use `Collection` objects, as these are much more dynamic and flexible with regards to size variation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description you've given, follow my suggestion.

Please, give us your feedback.

```
Private Function AmazingFunction(inputArray As Variant)
    Dim size As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim tmp As Variant
    Dim newArray() As Variant

    size = UBound(inputArray) ' Array size
    ReDim newArray(size) ' Resizes another array to the same size

    For i = 0 To size ' For each value
        tmp = CreateArray(length:=0) ' Allows you to dynamically create arrays
                                     ' In this case, an array of only one element is created.
        tmp(0) = inputArray(i) ' Sets the value of the first array element
        newArray(i) = tmp
    Next

    AmazingFunction = newArray
End Function
```

Auxiliary function to create arrays dynamically:

```
Private Function CreateArray(length As Long)
    Dim arr() As Variant
    ReDim arr(length)
    CreateArray = arr
End Function
```

Here is an example of how to use the function:

```
Private Sub UseTest()
    Dim outArray As Variant
    Dim intArray As Variant
    Dim element As Variant

    Dim inputArray(2) As Variant

    inputArray(0) = "a"
    inputArray(1) = "b"
    inputArray(2) = "c"
    outArray = AmazingFunction(inputArray)

    For Each intArray In outArray
        For Each element In intArray
            Debug.Print element
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for yout time! I had to change the code to ReDim newArray(size) because I was getting an out of interval error.